# Effect of duplicate Redis subscription to same channel name

Tags: redis

To subscribe to an instance of StackExchange.Redis.ISubscriber one needs to call the following API:

```
void Subscribe(RedisChannel channel, Action<RedisChannel, RedisValue> handler, CommandFlags flags = CommandFlags.None);
```

Question is, what happens if one calls this same line of code with the same channel name as a simple string, say "TestChannel"?

Does ISubscriber check for string equality or it just does not care and therefore we will have two subscriptions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am making an assumption that your question is targeted at the *Redis API* itself. Please let me know if it isn't.

The answer is also based on the assumption that you are using a single redis client connection.

The *pubsub* map is a [hashtable](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/3.2.6/src/dict.h).

To answer your question: If you subscribe multiple times with the same string, you will continue to have only one subscription(you can see that the subscribe happens based on the hashtable here: https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/3.2.6/src/pubsub.c#L64.

Conversely, calling a single unsubscribe will unsubscribe your other subscriptions for that channel/pattern as well.

If it helps, here is a simple example in Go (I have used the go-redis library) that illustrates the unsubscribe and hashtable storage parts of the answer.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"

    "github.com/go-redis/redis"
)

func main() {
    cl := redis.NewClient((&redis.Options{
        Addr:     "127.0.0.1:6379",
        PoolSize: 1,
    }))

    ps := cl.Subscribe()

    err := ps.Subscribe("testchannel")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    err = ps.Subscribe("testchannel")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    err = ps.Unsubscribe("testchannel")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    go func() {
        msg, err := ps.ReceiveMessage()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(msg.Payload)
    }()

    err = cl.Publish("testchannel", "some value").Err()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A channel may have multiple subscribers. All client who subscribe to the same channel will receive the messages published on this given channel.

Comment: I think OP means what happens if  the *same* client subscribes multiple times